# How do I require JS files within the same directory properly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

I'm having trouble understanding how require() works in JS.

Here's the issue I'm having:

My folder structure looks like this:

```
test

  ->test

    ->a.js

    ->b.js

    ->c.js
```

And here is the code I have in each file:

In `c.js`:

```
function c() {
  console.log("c")
}

module.exports = c;
```

In `b.js`:

```
let c = require("./c");

function b() {
  c();
  console.log("b");
}

exports.b = b;
```

In `a.js`:

```
let b = require("./test/b")
```

When I execute the code in `a.js`, it runs fine.

But when I execute the code in `b.js` it throws an error:

```
module.js:472
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './c'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at [stdin]:3:9
    at ContextifyScript.Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:23:33)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:95:38)
    at Object.<anonymous> ([stdin]-wrapper:6:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at evalScript (bootstrap_node.js:391:27)
```

But when I change the contents of `b.js` to be:

```
let c = require("./test/c");

function b() {
  c();
  console.log("b");
}

module.exports = b;
```

Now `a.js` throws an error:

```
module.js:472
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './test/c'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/sp/Desktop/test/test/b.js:1:71)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
```

What am I not understanding?

Comment: To load a file in the same directory as the current module, you would prefix the filename with `./`.  So, to load `x.js` from `y.js` where both are in the same directory, you would just do `require('./x.js')`.

Comment: But that throws an error. For some reason, whenever I require a file I have to input the full directory.

Comment: It shouldn't throw an error try omitting the ./ and just x.js, a relative path is valid ./ is giving you an absolute path. try it without the ./ and use a relative path. ./ is shorthand notation for /System/User/yourname/currentdirectory/ you can also use CLI and pwd will give you the absolute path to use, there is also a global variable that stores the path

Comment: Then you're doing something out of the ordinary.  How are you running these files?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're running them all from `/test/` root directory.

Running `a.js` from root: `./test/b` points to `/test/test/b`

Running `b.js` from root: `./c` points to `/test/c` which does not exist.

When you run `a.js` from root, it requires `b.js` from `./test/b` which then requires `c.js` going the relative path from its own directory via `./c` - that's why it's working if you run `a.js`.

Now running `b.js` from upper `/test/` directory results in `b.js` looking for `c.js` in `/test/c` instead of `/test/test/c`.

Changing `b.js` to `let c = require("./test/c");` leads to the following:

`a.js` still requires `b.js` from `./test/b` aka `/test/test/b`. Now `b.js` tries to require from `./test/c` pointing to non existent `/test/test/test/c`.

Answer (score 0):

Node looks for a `module` object from a file it `require()`s. Specifically looking at `module.exports`

```
// File a.js
const foo = "Hello"
module.exports = foo
```

```
// File b.js
const bar = "World"
module.exports = bar
```

```
// File index.js
const a = require('./a')
const b = require('./b')

console.log(a, b) //Hello World
```

You can also export objects

```
module.exports = { foo, bar }
```

Which you import like this

```
const { foo, bar} = require("./file")
```

And when you don't specify a location, it looks in `node_modules`

```
const express = require('express') // Looks inside node_modules for express
```